# c#: How do i remove "broken" chars from a string? �

Tags: c#, string, encoding

My application runs cmd commands and saves the output in a string. Whenever there is a german umlaut in the output, the content looks for example like this:

```
Id Name                 MainWindowTitle     
14892 TextInputHost        Microsoft Text Input Application                                                
6712 VirtualBox           Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager                                                    
2124 VirtualBoxVM         Win10_2 [wird ausgef�hrt] - Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

How do i replace/remove the broken chars? like the �, because it doesnt let me encode the string in base64 without information loss.

```
string activeProcesses = SysHelper.GetForegroundProcesses(); //runs a cmd-process and returns the string with the broken character above
```

Comment: How are you viewing the string? Is this a console application which outputs to cmd, and you're reading the string in a cmd window, for example?

Comment: i create a process with System.Diagnostic.Process, call cmd.exe with the command as parameter and read the output of the process with cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Comment: How are you actually viewing the output? Yes it's stored in a string, but how are you viewing the string?

Comment: (This is an encoding issue, and we need to figure out at what point in the pipeline things are going wrong. You don't want to just remove such characters - you should fix the encoding problem)

Comment: The most likely problem is that `ProcessStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding` is set incorrectly: on .NET Framework this will default to the Windows code page; on .NET Core, it will default to UTF-8. If you don't know what encoding your process is outputting in, try setting this to the usual suspects: `Encoding.UTF8`, `Encoding.Default`, `CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage);` on .NET Core, 1250, 1252, etc

Comment: my application is running as a windows service (user is system) and sometimes i have to run some commands as the logged on user. In those cases i use the windows API in c# and run CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, null, command, ref saProcessAttributes, ref saThreadAttributes, false, NOWINDOW, IntPtr.Zero, ".", ref si, out pi). The code is quite complex (several hundred lines). I see no way to edit the encoding there. So is there any way to just remove the bad chars from the string?

Comment: i convert the string to base64, and decode it later. The base64 gets completly broken as soon as there is a "broken" char -> thats my problem and thats why i need to get rid of it. If i try to decode it, its just random alien signs after the first � appears.

Comment: You get this "replacement character" when the incoming bytes don't form a valid character in whatever the current encoding is. There is no way to get back the "ü". The correct solution is to somehow select the correct encoding. A temporary solution may be to just replace it with empty string or "?".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was, that the "broken" char, prevented me from encoding the string to base64. If I did, the base64 string was broken and when decoding it, I received only alien signs.

I fixed it, by using

```
string processStrClean = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(activeProcesses));
```

instead of

```
string processStrClean = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(activeProcesses));
```

So, actually, it was the UTF8 encoding, which broke it. After using the Default encoding, I could encode the string into a base64 string and later decode it, without loss of information.

And always remember, kids, real heroes answer their own questions at stack overflow, once they find out the solution to their problem. Maybe someone finds this thread in 5 years and you save his day.